# It is possible to save an Object on a Button on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, button

I was woldering if it is possible save an Object into a Button on Xamarin.Forms, C#. This is my code:

```
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage{
    public MenuPage(List<Product> products) {
        InitializeComponent();

        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        int product_cont = 0;

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 3; rowIndex++) {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 2; columnIndex++) {
               Button b = new Button();
               b.Text = products[products_cont].name;
               b.OnButtonClicked += async (sender, e) => {
                   //go to products childs
                   await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(products[products_cont].childs));
               };
               i++; //next product
               grid.Children.Add(b, columnIndex, rowIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The buttoms shows correctly, but when I press them, `products[products_cont].childs` doesn't exist. I think if I could do somethings like this it will work fine:

```
...
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = products[products_cont].name;
b.SAVE_OBJECT(products[products_cont])
b.OnButtonClicked += async (sender, e) => {
   //go to products childs
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(b.GET_OBJECT.childs));
};
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the `BindingContext`

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = products[products_cont].name;
b.BindingContext = products[products_cont];
b.OnButtonClicked += NavigateToProduct;
```

and

```
protected void NavigateToProduct(object sender, EventArgs a)
{                   
    var btn = (Button)sender);
    var product = (Product)sender.BindingContext;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(product.childs));
}
```